# How to publish a folder containing some necessary files inside a project

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, clickonce

I am going to publish a C# windows form application project. 
I have a folder named "Reports" Containing some report file. 
when I publish the project , my application cannot find the path of reports.
How can I publish my Reports inside the project?

Comment: Do you publish using `ClickOnce`?

Comment: Are the report files included in the project and marked "Copy to Output Directory", or is it a public directory on a server somewhere?

Comment: No , It has not any special mark. just a simple folder.

Comment: @Behnam You should first set the file to `Copy to Output Directory`. This way your files will copy to output directory. Then if you want to use `Publish` command, in Publish tab of Project properties you should include files by `Application Files` and choose your files.

Answer (score 2):

From solution explorer, choose each file that you need to include in the publish and in the properties of the file set `Copy to Output Directory` to `true`.  This way your files will be included in `bin\debug` folder of your application in their current folder names.

Then if you want to use `Publish` command, go to properties of the project, in publish tab, click on `Application Files` and check `Show All Files` and change the `Publish Status` of the files you need to `Include`.

Pay attention, if your file's `Build Action` is `Embedded Resource` then you don't need to do anything else to include in the publish because it's included (embedded) in resources of your application.

Comment: I cannot find my report in application files .

Comment: If you are using rdlc reports usually they are included in resources and you don't need to do anything else for them.

Comment: I am using stimulsoft Report (mrt).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know where the stimulsoft reports will be created and how the will be used. Anyway you should know if the files are included in resources (the build action of them is embedded resource) then they don't need more action to do, but if their action is not embedded resource, you should copy them to output directory. And follow the instructions in the answer.